# Create admin module and configuration in Zend Framework 1.9.0

Tags: zend-framework

I am working with zend framework for last 2 months. I got zend framework latest version 1.9.0.

I am new in zend framework programming. I am learning one by one.. in zend framework. Now i am confused with creating admin module in zend and their configuration settings. Please help me to create admin module with in the module folder in zend framework.

Thanks and regards,

Prasanth P

Answer (score 3):

Using Zend_Tool you can create modules.

```
zf create module name
```

I did have a few issues when creating modules these two blogs were a great help (few articles on each). I was looking to have separate configs, layouts ect for each one, maybe not what you're after but good read anyway.

http://blog.vandenbos.org/2009/07/07/zend-framework-module-config/

Comment: http://blog.keppens.biz/2009/07/zend-framework-module-specific-config.html

can't post two links :(

Comment: Thanks let me check with that.. I hope the blog will help me to build modules zend framework.

Thanks and regards,

Prasanth P

Comment: I had a problem when using Zend Tool to make the modules as it thought the controller index was already in use so I did end up making Controllers manually but the bootstrapping worked and directory creation worked a treat.

Comment: Hi...

Any other options to add modules in zend framework. I check with the blog that you referred. I think it will not help me to create module in zend framework 1.9.0. Please give me any other link.. :),

Regards,
Prasanth P

Comment: i mean the links you give.. little bit confusing for me :P.. don't take miss understand me.. :)

Comment: http://blog.keppens.biz/2009/06/create-modular-application-with-zend.html - This has details how to start

Comment: i suppose theres the documentation too : 
http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.tool.framework.clitool.html

Answer (score 2):

We have a similar problem:
I am designing a large scale application with about 5 modules. 
Even though I am not finding my way around, I think this blog post http://blog.astrumfutura.com/archives/415-Self-Contained-Reusable-Zend-Framework-Modules-With-Standardised-Configurators.html might be helpful for you and for anybody else. Please, update this thread if you find anything interesting. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[use of this](http://www.skyrocket.be/2009/01/11/admin-cms-routes-in-zend-framework/)

http://www.skyrocket.be/2009/01/11/admin-cms-routes-in-zend-framework/